# Flattened field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a doubt where there is a field and there are multiple values of that field and to find the result of the exact value in that fieldvalue
Below is the example aBsorb is a field name and logs-mask* is index.
Example:

```
aBsorb : {This is paragraph full of strings and values, "ABCD" : "PL1234", "SRTS" : "GH879"}
```

I should write query to find value of

```
aBsorb : "ABCD" : "PL1234"
```

I have tried nested query and should i write in DSL

Comment: How does your mapping look like?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `aBsorb` field is  a JSON string, instead of true nested field. If this is the case, querying on such a field can be a bit more challenging, because the content might work as a plain string by Elasticsearch.
Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "aBsorb.keyword": "{\"ABCD\" : \"PL1234\"}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

PS: if you provide your mappings I can provide exact solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried with the same query in DSL no results coming up when I have the hits.

Comment: Can you try this: `{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "aBsorb",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "aBsorb.ABCD": "PL1234"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`